# What is the best way to match a probiotic suppliment to desired strains?

Tags: probiotics

Looking for a probotic suppliment with the following strains:

- Lactobacillus Plantarm
- Lactobacillus Acidophilus
- Lactobacillus Brevis
- Bifidobacterum Lactis
- Bifidobacterum Longum

What is the best way to match a probiotic suppliment to desired strains?

Would one need to look at the back of every product supplement out there and try to match each species or is there a better way to find the right probiotic with desired species?

Are there classes or categories of probiotcs?

Are there certain standards or certifications to look for?

Are there trusted studies on which brands work best?